# npx create react app command is not functioning

Tags: node.js, reactjs

im getting this error when I try to run npm create-react-app

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-05T10_49_53_229Z-debug-0.log

How should I overcome this problem? Thanks

Comment: What is the full command you're running, what version of Node and NPM do you have installed (`node -v`, `npm -v`), and could you post the last few lines of the debug log?